# Attuinity connectors SSIS package migrate to SSIS 2022

Tags: sql-server, sql, microsoft, ssis

I have 2015 SSIS solution with attuinity oracle connectors, I am unable to open the package in VS 2022 since it does not support attuinity any more, I get Object reference not set to instance of the object error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Attunity Oracle Connector was deprecated in SQL Server 2019 and replaced by the Microsoft Connector for Oracle. However, there is a workaround that you can try to open and modify your package in Visual Studio 2022, please try the following steps:

1. Install the new Microsoft Connector for Oracle from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver16).
2. Once you have opened the SSIS package on Visual Studio 2022, in the Solution Explorer, right-click on your project and select Properties. In the Configuration Properties tab, change the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2019 or above. This should automatically upgrade your package to use the Microsoft Connector for Oracle instead of the Attunity Oracle Connector.